# Why does blueJ try to execute my program forever

Tags: java, bluej

I'm not sure if it a problem with my code or not but when I try to run the code with a string that is longer than about 50 characters BlueJ tries to run the program forever and the console never comes up. I left it running for an hour or so still no results.

I've tried entering a variety of strings directly into the program and it seems that shorter strands of DNA entered work fine but after a certain length the program never executes and I'm not sure what the issue could be because no error messages or exceptions are shown.

```
package com.company;

public class problem3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new problem3().printAllGenes("CAATGCTGATAGTAATGGTATTATGATATGTAGTGGGATTTAGAGGATGCGCGCAGCCGATGACGAGCGACGATGCTAA");
    }

    public int findStopCodon(String dnaStr, int startIndex, String stopCodon) {
        int currIndex = dnaStr.indexOf(stopCodon, startIndex + 3);
        while (currIndex != -1) {
            int diff = currIndex - startIndex;
            if (diff % 3 == 0) {
                return currIndex;
            } else {
                currIndex = dnaStr.indexOf(stopCodon, currIndex+1);
            }
        }
        return dnaStr.length();
    }

    public String findGene(String dna, int where) {
        int startIndex = dna.indexOf("ATG", where);

        if (startIndex == -1) {
            return "";

        }
        int taaIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TAA");
        int tagIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TAG");
        int tgaIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TGA");
        int minIndex = 0;

        if (taaIndex == -1 || (tgaIndex != -1 && tgaIndex < taaIndex)) {
            minIndex = tgaIndex;

        } else {
            minIndex = taaIndex;
        }
        if (minIndex == -1 || (tagIndex != -1 && tagIndex < minIndex)) {
            minIndex = tagIndex;
        }
        if (minIndex == -1) {

            return "";
        }
        if (minIndex + 3 > dna.length()) {
            return "";
        }

        return dna.substring(startIndex, minIndex + 3);
    }

    public void printAllGenes(String dna) {

        int startIndex = 0;

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("yes");
            String currentGene = findGene(dna, startIndex);

            if (currentGene.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(currentGene);

            startIndex = dna.indexOf(currentGene, startIndex) + currentGene.length();
        }

    }
}
```

The program is supposed to take a strand of DNA and p out genes by finding start codons (ATG) and stop codon (TAA, TAG, TGA). To run the program I would call the printAllGenes() method with String dna = "CAATGCTGATAGTAATGGTATTATGATATGTAGTGGGATTTAGAGGATGCGCGCAGCCGATGACGAGCGACGATGCTAA".

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change

```
currIndex = dnaStr.indexOf(stopCodon, currIndex);
```

in `findStopCodon` to

```
currIndex = dnaStr.indexOf(stopCodon, currIndex + 1);
```

Because otherwise you will always find the same `currIndex` and never exit the `while` loop.